# Global Hover style with color:inherit|currentColor

Tags: html, css

I'm playing with CSS trying to implement a feature when a user can change the base color of the site. I managed to achieve the possibility to change the base color by designing my markup and styles like so:

```
body {
  color: black;
}
body elem {
  color: inherit; /* or currentColor */
}
```

This solution works for static elements... but what about Hover effect?
Is there any way to set the hover-color to something, so that it will be recursively fetched by nested elements?
Trying to use CSS only. Any advice? Thanks.

[here's the simplest example. change the color value for body and the nested elements will use the new value as well.](http://codepen.io/netgoblin/pen/JEmiy)

JavaScript solutions are too easy =)

Comment: i.e. body > elem { *** }

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "it will be recursively fetched by nested elements"? With an example, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe easiest using a class for the elements that should use a specific hover color – `<foo class="hovercolor">…</foo>` and `.hovercolor:hover { color: valuefromuserinput; }`. Otherwise, you might want to look into LESS or SASS, where you can specify the color value as a variable and use it in different places …

Comment: You could look into implementing a [stylesheet switcher](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-simple-easy-jquery-style-switchers/).

Comment: What should hover color be set to?

Comment: color should be set to whatever color value can be =)

Comment: I still don't understand. What's wrong with just `elem:hover { color: whatever }` for whatever element and color like you would normally do?

Comment: see the example, you can change the color of body tag ONLY and every element on the page will react! i want to know if there's a way to achieve the same effect with hover-effect. but if i set body:hover{} and hover something on the whole page the page will change as hover-event will bubble up to the body...